# Python Dataframe - replace NaN value with an existing value from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate two dataframes together which expectedly results in NaN values being created for columns X and Y.

```
d1 = {'Name':['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5'],
     'Value':[1,2,3,4,5],
     'X':[10,10,20,20,30],
     'Y':[10,20,10,20,10]} 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'Name':['X1','X2','X2','X3'],    
     'Value':[8,6,5,12]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df1.append(df2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I would like to update the NaN values in cols X and Y with the corresponding values already populated in df1.

For example any instance of a row containing `df1['Name'] == 'X1'` would have the same `df1['X']` and `df1['Y']` values as those associated with `df1['Name'] == 'X1'`.

In this example the values would be: Name = X1, X = 10, Y = 10.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`groupby ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-ffill):

```
new_df = df1.append(df2).reset_index(drop=True)
new_df[['X', 'Y']] = new_df.groupby('Name')[['X', 'Y']].ffill()
```

`new_df`:

```
  Name  Value     X     Y
0   X1      1  10.0  10.0
1   X2      2  10.0  20.0
2   X3      3  20.0  10.0
3   X4      4  20.0  20.0
4   X5      5  30.0  10.0
5   X1      8  10.0  10.0
6   X2      6  10.0  20.0
7   X2      5  10.0  20.0
8   X3     12  20.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out = df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
```

Another way via `fillna()` and `groupby()`:

```
out.fillna(out.groupby('Name')[['X','Y']].transform('first'),inplace=True)
```

**OR**

```
out[['X', 'Y']] = out.groupby('Name')[['X', 'Y']].fillna(method='ffill')
```

output of `out`:

```
  Name  Value     X     Y
0   X1      1  10.0  10.0
1   X2      2  10.0  20.0
2   X3      3  20.0  10.0
3   X4      4  20.0  20.0
4   X5      5  30.0  10.0
5   X1      8  10.0  10.0
6   X2      6  10.0  20.0
7   X2      5  10.0  20.0
8   X3     12  20.0  10.0
```